# array of pointers allocation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, allocation

typedef struct
    {
      struct table **symbols; // array of the stack
      int top; //index of the top element
      int size; //maximum size of the stack
    }stack;

```
void *createStack(int size)
{
  stack *stck;
  stck = (stack *) malloc(sizeof(stack));

  stck->symbols  = ....

  stck->size = size;
  stck->top = -1;
  printf("stack is created --> size is : %d \n",size);
}
```

Here I need to allocate my stack's symbol array which is "..." but I couldn't figure out it's syntax, pls help : )

Comment: Don't forget to check that the `malloc`s succeed!

Comment: Avoid malloc if you know the exact size at compile time.
How large an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(struct table **)malloc(size * sizeof(struct table*));
```

But that's if you want to pre-allocate all the space at once. If you want to allocate more as you go, you could start with something smaller than `size` and allocate more in your push() function when you run out of space.

Answer (score 4):

```
malloc(size * sizeof(struct table*));
```

Comment: Might be desired to include the cast.

Comment: No in C explicit cast is not required.

Comment: My bad :)... it's just me that likes to be explicit then.

Comment: Explicitly casting the return value of malloc in C can hide errors (such as neglecting to #include stdlib.h).  Avoid doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Is symbols intended to be a 1-d array of pointer to struct table or a 2-d array of struct table?

```
stck->symbols = malloc(sizeof *(stck->symbols) * numberOfElements);
```

for whatever value of `numberOfElements`.  Given that the type of stck->symbols is `struct table **`, the type of the expression `*(stck->symbols)` will be `struct table *`.  You could also write

```
malloc(sizeof (struct table*) * numberOfElements);
```

but I prefer the former method, as it minimizes the number of places you have to remember the type.

As this is C, you do *not* need to cast the result of `malloc()`, and it's considered poor practice to do so; if you forget to include stdlib.h or otherwise don't have a prototype for `malloc()` in scope, the cast will supress a warning alerting you to the problem (although since C99 no longer allows implicit int typing, that may no longer be an issue).

Answer (score 0):

```
stck->symbols  = baseaddress = malloc(...required total size...);

int nextDataLocation = baseAddress + numberOfRows*sizeof(void*);

for(int i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++)
{
    stck->symbols[i] = nextDataLocation;
    ..copy string i to address stck->symbols[i]...
    nextDataLocation += lengthOfString[i];
}
```